# Entity Framework : ChangeTracker loads all my table elements

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This is the code of my `MyService` class:

```
public class MyService
{
    public IEnumerable<Foo> FoosNotDeleted
    {
        get { return Db.Foos.Where(v => !v.Deleted); }
    }

    public List<Foo> GetByMyFK(int fk)
    {
          List<Foo> test = Db.Foos.Where(v => !v.Deleted)
                                  .Where(v => v.FK == fk).ToList();

          // I get 0 in my case as the context did not play with any Foo yet
          int entriesCount = Db.ChangeTracker.Entries<Foo>().Count(); 

          List<Foo> test = FoosNotDeleted.Where(v => v.FK == fk).ToList();

          // I get 15K (meaning all my non deleted foos)
          entriesCount = Db.ChangeTracker.Entries<Foo>().Count(); 
    }
}
```

Why does the context load all of the non deleted Foo elements in the second case? Both cases look exactly the same to me!

After the `ChangeTracker.Entries` loads these 15K elements, performance collapses and every insert takes 500ms instead of 2-3 ms. :)

Answer (score 2):

This is because `FoosNotDeleted` returns a Collection, not a Query.  All the rows where `!v.Deleted` is true are returned to the client for evaluation of the `v => v.FK = fk` predicate.

Running `.AsEnumerable()`, `.ToList()`, `.ToArray()`, or casting to `IEnumerable<T>` and applying additional query predicates will transition you from server-side to client-side execution.

An easy fix is to use `IQueryable<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>` for your `FoosNotDeleted` property.

```
public IQueryable<Foo> FoosNotDeleted
{
    get { return Db.Foos.Where(v => !v.Deleted); }
}
```

Comment: Works fine. Thx a ton :)